# REGEX: Searching for events containing "cmaeventd" but not the number "2424"

Tags: regex

I would like to search for events containing "*cmaeventd*" but not the number  "*2424*". I'm using RHEL.

For example, if I have the following lines:

```
HP Appliance Hardware Error: Jun 20 22:41:30 pnn-a cmaeventd[2424]: Surface Analysis Pass Information, LDrv=0 Number of passes=34
HP Appliance Hardware Error: Jun 20 22:41:30 pnn-a cmaeventd[2624]: Surface Analysis Pass Information, LDrv=0 Number of passes=34
HP Appliance Hardware Error: Jun 20 22:41:30 pnn-a cmaeventd[2484]: Surface Analysis Pass Information, LDrv=0 Number of passes=34
```

the regex should extract only the lines:

```
HP Appliance Hardware Error: Jun 20 22:41:30 pnn-a cmaeventd[2624]: Surface Analysis Pass Information, LDrv=0 Number of passes=34
HP Appliance Hardware Error: Jun 20 22:41:30 pnn-a cmaeventd[2484]: Surface Analysis Pass Information, LDrv=0 Number of passes=34
```

since the event numbers are different from 2424.

I'm not used to regular expressions.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Without information about the system you are using regular expressions within, you are less likely to receive answers which are correct and useful for your scenario.  Please review the [`regex` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) and [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31023189/edit) with pertinent details to help us help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this regex: `.*(?=cmaeventd)(?!.*2424).+`

See this [**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/iC0vQ6/1) to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a duplicate.

```
awk '/cmaeventd/ && ! /2424/' logfile
```

Based on your examples, I guess you really want to focus on excluding lines where 2424 occurs in square brackets immediately after `cmaeventd`.  You need backslashes because the square brackets have special meaning.

```
awk '/cmaeventd/ && !/cmaeventd\[2424\]/' logfile
```